# Usage of じゃないか when not a tag question or a negative question

Tags: grammar, tag-question

[This answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/59391/7944) had the following translation:

> そんなに笑わなくてもいいじゃありませんか。
>   You don't have to laugh like that.
>   (Please, don't laugh at me like that!)

I haven't seen じゃありませんか (じゃないか) used like this before. I would have tried to translate this as "It's ok not to laugh so much, isn't it?"

Firstly, is my translation attempt wrong? Secondly, could someone please give a bit more explanation (and maybe some examples) of how it is used in the above sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say your translation is pretty good. I'd personally translate it as "There's no need to laugh that hard." じゃないか is basically conveying a bit of petulance, like "this isn't necessary", or, more literally, "it's fine if you don't laugh [so much], isn't it?", rather than an actual question.